# Converting a number into a special base system

Tags: algorithm, converters, radix

I want to convert a number in base 10 into a special base form like this:

A*2^2 + B*3^1 + C*2^0

A can take on values of [0,1]

B can take on values of [0,1,2]

C can take on values of [0,1]

For example, the number 8 would be

1*2^2 + 1*3 + 1.

It is guaranteed that the given number can be converted to this specialized base system.

I know how to convert from this base system back to base-10, but I do not know how to convert from base-10 to this specialized base system.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You say you want to convert to A*4 + B*3 + C. The max, given your choices, would be 1*4 + 2*3 + 1 = 11. At most you have 12 values to convert, so a simple table (or case statement) should handle it fine.

Comment: In this case, a table might work. However, when I have to convert it to a similar but longer form like A*4^2 + B*2^3 + C*5^1 + D*5^0 a table wouldn't work. Is there any way to do it like the regular base conversion algorithm.

Comment: The issue with the problem as stated is that the solution space for A, B, C is limited. If you allowed C to go {-1,0,1} for example, you could make combinations of B-C (power of 2) and just C . Then you can express your number as a binary, and solve for A, B, and C. But when C cannot go negative, that trick goes away.

Comment: It seems to me you've simply described a bin packing problem.  Unless a "greedy" algorithm works (I haven't analyzed that) you're venturing into that NP-whatever territory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short words, treat every base number (2^2, 3^1, 2^0 in your example) as weight of an item, and the whole number as the capacity of a bag. This problem wants us to find a combination of these items which they fill the bag exactly.

In the first place this problem is NP-complete. It is identical to the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which can also be seen as a derivative problem of the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Despite this fact, this problem can however be solved by a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm using dynamic programming in `O(nW)` time, which `n` is the number of bases, and `W` is the number to decompose. The details can be find in this wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming and this SO page: [What's it called when I want to choose items to fill container as full as possible - and what algorithm should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790554/whats-it-called-when-i-want-to-choose-items-to-fill-container-as-full-as-possib).

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying your "special base":

```
X = A * 4 + B * 3 + C
A E {0,1}
B E {0,1,2}
C E {0,1}
```

Obviously the largest number that can be represented is `4 + 2 * 3 + 1 = 11`

To figure out how to get the values of A, B, C you can do one of two things:

1. There are only 12 possible inputs: create a lookup table. Ugly, but quick.
2. Use some algorithm. A bit trickier.

Let's look at (1) first:

A B C  X
0 0 0  0
0 0 1  1
0 1 0  3
0 1 1  4
0 2 0  6
0 2 1  7
1 0 0  4
1 0 1  5
1 1 0  7
1 1 1  8
1 2 0 10
1 2 1 11

Notice that `2` and `9` cannot be expressed in this system, while `4` and `7` occur twice. The fact that you have multiple possible solutions for a given input is a hint that there isn't a really robust algorithm (other than a look up table) to achieve what you want.  So your table might look like this:

```
int A[] = {0,0,-1,0,0,1,0,1,1,-1,1,1};
int B[] = {0,0,-1,1,1,0,2,1,1,-1,2,2};
int C[] = {0,1,-1,0,2,1,0,1,1,-1,0,1};
```

Then look up A, B, C. If A < 0, there is no solution.